# Convert pointer address to char array and make it little-endian

Tags: c, linux, string, pointers

In C, if I have a:

```
char *ptr;
```

and if, let's say, `ptr` points to address `0xbfc70753`, how can I convert it to an array of char so that I end up with an array of char `addr` that will contain:

```
char addr[4] = "\x53\x07\xc7\xbf"
```

That is, **convert the address pointed at by `ptr` to an array of char and make it little-endian.**

(Kali Linux, 32 bit, intel)

Comment: Can you please try to refine the question, it will be easier to get what you are missing. What `SHELLCODE` contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a little-endian machine, this is a nice way to do it:

```
void foo(uint32_t* adr, uint32_t value){*adr = value;}


int main(int argc, char** argc)
{
    char *ptr = ...
    char adr[4];

    foo((uint32_t*)adr,(uint32_t)ptr);
}
```

The idea is that 32-bit unsigned integers are already in little-endian, so when you copy them to a char array, each byte goes to the place you want.

Comment: I'm sure this is a joke answer, but still, you can't cast to some other type and dereference.

Comment: @self Actually this indeed worked and I'm accepting it as the answer. Nice trick Cantfindname!

Comment: Actually casting to another type and dereferencing is useful some times. For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Answer (score 4):

In C, pointer width (ie number of bytes used to represent a pointer) is not guaranteed. You know your platform, so you could code just for this, but your code will not be portable in all likelihood.

The technique shown in one of the answers may work, but it has a couple of weaknesses,

```
char *ptr = ...
char adr[4];                     //<< Not a great idea! See below...

*(uint32_t*)adr = (uint32_t)ptr; //<< Not a great idea! See below...
```

The first weakness is that the size of a pointer may not be 4 bytes. What if, for example, you ever ran you code on a 64-bit system? To get around this problem you will be best using `uintptr_t`. The C99 standard (Sect. 7.18.1.4) defines this type as a...

> ...an unsigned integer type with the property that any
>   valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted
>   back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the
>   original pointer...

[***This article***](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0050/) gives a pretty good explanation of why pointer width may vary between architectures and how types such as `uintptr_t`, `size_t` etc can help out.

The next possible problem is type aliasing. This occurs when two variables point to the same bit of memory. This is a problem because the C compiler will assume that two objects with different *effective types* will not reference overlapping memory locations.

Effective type is defined in Sect 6.5 as:

> The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of
>   the object, if any

Where the issue of type casting and type punning comes in is where the standard says (I've paraphrased a bit to shorten it)...

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a (qualified version of a) type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the (qualified) effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types
>   among its members, or
>
> — a character type.

In the above example the type of `adr` is pointer-to-character-array. A 32-bit integer is *not* a [***compatible***](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc03compatible_types.htm) type with char. Therefore this violates the first rule so could result in UB (undefined behavior).

Why should this be a problem? The answer, on some systems, lies in data alignment. [***This article***](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/) is very useful on this subject. Some systems may assume and require that access to a `uint32_t` type is done on a 4-byte aligned boundary. But, your `char` array has no such restriction. Therefore if the array started on a non-4-byte-aligned location, accessing it with the aliasing unsigned integer pointer could cause a hardware exception, for example. [***The following article***](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/) talks more about other issues with type aliasing in much greater depth, more specifically to do with type punning too.

Okay, so what can you do to get around this? Something like the following would provide you a solution...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t i;
    char const *ptr = "Some string";
    char adr[sizeof(void *) + 1]; // Note the +1 to make room for NULL terminator
    uintptr_t ptrAddress = (uintptr_t)ptr;

    printf("Pointer address is %p\n", ptr);
    printf("Converting to 0x");
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(void *); ++i)
    {
        adr[i] = ptrAddress & 0xff;
        printf("%2.2X", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)adr[i]);
        ptrAddress >>= 8;
    }
    printf("\n");
    adr[sizeof(void *)] = '\0';


    return 0;
}
```

Now the array `adr` will always have the correct size for the size of pointers on your system. It will also store the value of the pointer little endian because the least significant byte of the address is stored in the first array location (lowest address) and so on.

[***See working example of the above on oneide...***](http://ideone.com/P7lTDx)

Comment: Thank you for this. It definitely works but it's pushing my knowledge of C to its current limits! I will need to go over your explanation and read the articles to understand it all.
Although your code is working, I can no longer concatenate 'adr' to a larger payload string (I'm playing with buffer overflow) and write it to a file. strcat (badconfig, adr) throws a Segmentation Fault, using the Cantfindname's (bad?) solution did allow me to concantenate.

Comment: I think what is happening is that the buffer in the code example is not NULL terminated. In the working example on oneide.com, the last link, it is and I print it out. Have a look at that. That should get rid of your string concatenation seg fault :) I've updated my answer too.

Comment: Also, do you want to store the address in the char buffer so that the bytes are little endian or so that it prints out correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, probably there is a place for UB, but it worked on my machine.
The idea is clear i guess, just print the pointer into char array.

```
int i =9,j;
int *p = &i;
char* pstr = malloc(sizeof(*p)*4);


sprintf(pstr,"%p",p);
for(j=0; j<sizeof(*p)*4;++j)
    printf("%c ",pstr[j]);


printf("\n%p",p);
```

Comment: Your code transforms the pointer into text: `53 07 c7 bf`. The OP wants to get the *bytes*: `"\x53\x07\xc7\xbf"`.

Comment: ... "so that I end up with an array of char addr that will contain:"

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like that should work: (I didn't test it)

```
unsigned int mask = 0xFF;
for(unsigned int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    addr[i] = (ptr & mask)>>(8*i);
    mask = mask<<8;
}
```